# Is there support in the .NET Framework to map .NET data types to their corresponding SqlDBType?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I'm curious if there is support in the .NET Framework to map .NET data types to the corresponding enumeration SqlDbType that represents the data type in SQL.

For Instance:

```
dim mySqlDbType as SqlDbType = SomeFunction(GetType(myObject))
```

Comment: Also another approach: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/ConvToSqlDbType.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`SqlMetadata.InferFromValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata.inferfromvalue.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Any open source code generation tool or O/RM should have a dictionary or function to map from SqlDbType to .NET type and back. For example, from [Data Tier Generator](http://www.codeplex.com/DataTierGenerator):

```
    internal static string GetCsType(Column column)
    {
        switch (column.Type.ToLower())
        {
            case "binary":
                return "byte[]";
            case "bigint":
                return "long";
            case "bit":
                return "bool";
            case "char":
                return "string";
            case "datetime":
                return "DateTime";
            case "decimal":
                return "decimal";
            case "float":
                return "float";
            case "image":
                return "byte[]";
            case "int":
                return "int";
            case "money":
                return "decimal";
            case "nchar":
                return "string";
            case "ntext":
                return "string";
            case "nvarchar":
                return "string";
            case "numeric":
                return "decimal";
            case "real":
                return "decimal";
            case "smalldatetime":
                return "DateTime";
            case "smallint":
                return "short";
            case "smallmoney":
                return "float";
            case "sql_variant":
                return "byte[]";
            case "sysname":
                return "string";
            case "text":
                return "string";
            case "timestamp":
                return "DateTime";
            case "tinyint":
                return "byte";
            case "varbinary":
                return "byte[]";
            case "varchar":
                return "string";
            case "uniqueidentifier":
                return "Guid";
            default:  // Unknow data type
                throw (new Exception("Invalid SQL Server data type specified: " + column.Type));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't like this approach because it doesn't scale.  What happens when Microsoft adds another value to SqlDbType?